# Call a public GraphQL API once a month

Tags: cron, graphql, scheduled-tasks

I would like to make a monthly call to a public GraphQL API with some minor business logic.

I read about Posthook but it is unclear how I can use it to call a GraphQL API. Posthook appears to only support REST.

What is an easy and reliable way to do this? Would it make sense to use an AWS Lambda or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL services typically [interact with clients over HTTP](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) with `POST` requests. Clients send JSON in the request and receive JSON in the response.

Some use cases benefit from a GraphQL client library like [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/), but plain old cURL works fine:

```sh
# request
curl --location --request POST 'https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"query":"query Query($filmId: ID) {\n  film(filmID: $filmId) {\n    title\n }\n}","variables":{"filmId":1}}'
```

```sh
# response
{"data":{"film":{"title":"A New Hope"}}}
```

An [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) (AWS's serverless function service) would be a fine way to implement a scheduled GraphQL api call and apply business logic.  The Lambda service integrates well with [cron-scheduled triggering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html) and [results notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-event-sources-and-destinations.html).  It's easy [to get started](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/run-serverless-code/).  You can set up the service by pointing-and-clicking in the AWS console. Or use a infrastructure-as-code library like AWS's [SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) (i.e. define your infra in YAML) or [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) (i.e. define your infra in JS/Python/etc).  Or in a squillion more ways.

The other cloud providers have similar offerings, take your pick.